# Inconsistency in python division operation

Tags: python, operators, division

I was performing simple division `x = a/b`, where *a = 314159265389793240* and *b=1*. The answer x was completely unexpected. x came out to be *3.141592653897932e+17*. This was really unexpected. Is there any way to do division in a consistent way? I am using python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, `/` is floating-point division. Both of your operands get coerced to floating point, and you get a floating point result. The floating point format does not have enough precision to hold your number exactly, so some of the later digits get fudged. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details.

Python 3 also has an integral division operator, `//`, which, if operands are integers, gives the result you expected.

```
print(314159265389793240 / 1)    # 3.141592653897932e+17
print(314159265389793240 // 1)   # 314159265389793240
```